# UI button change text

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, xcode5

I have level based game and under a view controller I have a button that says `start level 1`. I'm using it in aso so it'd be a mess to have a button for each level cause then there would be multiple layers. I'm sure you can just use one button and change the text of it once reached to a certain point by running some code but I don't know how I would program that in xcode 5.

Comment: If you share the code you have so far you will be more likely to get a response.

Comment: Posting the code you tried based on _basic research_ you've done like searching on [SO](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=uibutton+change+text) or [Google](https://www.google.com/#q=UIButton+change+text) for "UIButton change text" would have made a better question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`setTitle:forState:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIButton_Class/UIButton/UIButton.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIButton/setTitle%3aforState%3a) is the method you are looking for.

```
[button setTitle:@"Level 1" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```